# Populate List w/ data

Tags: java, for-loop, reflection, hashmap, javabeans

I have this code. The first for is to change line and the second for is to fill each line. With the first for I want to read the data from data[] and put it in different lines.

```
    List lista = new ArrayList();
    Bean line = new Bean();

    int j;
    int i;

    for (j = 1; j < data.length; j++) {
        LinkedHashMap<String, Object> hmap = (LinkedHashMap<String, Object>)data[j];

        for (i = 1; i < headers.length; i++) {
            line.choosefield(i,headers,hmap);
            }
        lista.add(line);
    }
```

I'm basically just getting the last line of my data[] (with the correct fields) repeated over and over. I think I could do something like

```
lista.add(line1,2,3...)
```

How can I do this and is there a better way? Using JDK 16. Thanks.

bean code:

```
public Object getField1() {
return field1;
}

public void setField1(Object field1) {
this.field1 = field1;
}

public Object getField2() {
return field2;
}

public void setField2(Object field2) {
this.field2 = field2;
}
...
public void choosefield(int i, String[] headers, LinkedHashMap<String, Object> hmap){

switch (i) {
case 1:
this.setField1(hmap.get(headers[1]));
break;
...
case 2:
this.setField2(hmap.get(headers[2]));
break;
```

data is an array of linked hashmaps with 17 fields

Comment: Hard to say what's wrong without viewing full picture of code structure. What is `data` object? What is `Bean` class? And so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you get the last element over and over again I'm taking a shot in the dark and guess you could try this:

```
for (i = 1; i < headers.length; i++) {
        Object obj = line.choosefield(i,headers,hmap);
        }
    lista.add( obj );
```

Whereat `obj` should have the type of your `chosefield` method.

Comment: I think I didn't make myself clear. I receive an array of linked hashmaps. The inner for populates each line individually and it's doing so correctly. The outer for is meant to fetch the data from each line of my array of hashmaps. My goal is to fetch the data from `(LinkedHashMap<String, Object>)data[j]` until `j<data.length`. What I'm getting so far is the last line of my array of hashmaps repeated over and over. Because, I think, line just gets the last index of data. If I could get data[1] put it in line1 data[2] in line 2 would work.

Answer (score 0):

Let's clear this out. This is the problem

```
List c1;
List c2;
List c3;
... so on to data.length[]

List lista = new ArrayList();

for (int i=0;i<data.length;i++)
{
LinkedHashMap<String, Object> hmap = (LinkedHashMap<String, Object>)data[i];
lista.add(//HOWTO: Add each of the answers?);
}
```

How can I implement this loop? I read that reflections is an option. How so?